# PHP: Formulario con cookie no puede modificar el header (cannot modify header information)

Tags: php, regex, cookies, setcookie

saludos.

tengo un problema con php y las cabeceras:

La cosa es que tengo un formulario en php donde al loguearse se envia un cookie.

Hasta aca está todo bien, pero al darle "submit" (enviar el formulario) me da este error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...

Lo curioso es que probando en localhost, el formulario funciona perfecto, pero no cuando lo uso en un servidor con mi dominio.

¿Que podría estar pasando? En teoría esta todo bien, ya que en localhost funciona sin problemas, pero no en mi hosting (probe con dos hostings diferenrtes). O sea, se envia el formulario pero no se setea la cookie con setcookie y sale ese warining.

Cosas que ya intenté:

- Ver si las etiquetas php estaban bien (sin espacios en blanco).
- Ver si no usaba algún header() despues del inicio del HTML.
- Ver si usaba algún caracter BOM (no uso BOM).
- Ver si el dominio de la cookie esta bien establecido.

Si alguno sabe, le agradecería algún consejo... Me extraña que en localhost funciona perfecto, pero no online.

Comment: Si nos muestras tu código podemos ayudarte de una mejor manera, sin el código no podemos valorar el problema...

Answer (score 0):

A mi me pasa a veces.
Suelen ser 2 cosas:
 1 - Que tengas un echo en la función del login
 2 - Que tengas algún espacio al principio o al final del archivo php.

Si posteas el codigo, ayudaría...XD

Como consejo, te digo que intentes tener en desarrollo y en producción la misma versión de servidor web, y sistema operativo para que no te pase lo de que te funcione en localhost y no en producción.